# How to change WP menu item type?

Tags: menus, admin

There seems to be no way to change menu item type from page to custom in wp admin. How can I do this? If I have big menu it’s very cumbersome to build these always by hand… Type change should be in the UI :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you wanting to put all your page URLs into custom menu items?

Comment: If I have menu say 7 main items and each has 5 subitems. If I want to change every main item to # it's a bit cumbersome to build the whole menu again. Item type change would be only one simple operation per main menu item :)

Comment: Ah, yeah I don't think there's any built-in way to do that. You would likely need to build a custom tool that updates them in the database. Or, you could try one of those automated tools like a browser extension where you can record automations -- perhaps it work for your case.